# Spring Boot Security Oauth2 - adding dynamic OIDC parameters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

How do I add OIDC token request parameters dynamically in my app code? I want to add *domain_hint* based on some data received by my controller from as yet un-authenticated user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement custom `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver`
and then add to your spring security configuration

```
.oauth2Login(req->
          req.authorizationEndpoint()
         .authorizationRequestResolver(new YourCustomAuthorizationRequestResolver)
 )
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks! You may also be able to use the `DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver` (so you don't have to create a whole custom RequestResolver) and then simply set a RequestCustomizer on it: `.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(builder -> builder.additionalParameters(Map.of("domain_hint", "gmail.com")));`

Comment: Yep, agree with you. But builder doesn’t allow to add an additional parameter dynamically from request as required by the post